# Multiple Image Upload to Multiple Mysql Field using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I have a php form where i have to save separate file /images by browsing file option  to separate mysql column and save / insert that by pressing one confirm button. I have checked many tutorial but couldn't find the exact tut to do this task.

the form view is given here: http://demo.softbd.com/student/registration/form-step-02/

Now suggest me how can i save these individual pictures in one attempt to mysql. I will only save the image path in mysql and move the image to a folder.

Any help is highly appreciated

SqL & PHP Code

```
     <?php 
$valid_formats = array("jpg","jpeg","JPG", "png", "gif", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*1024*1024;
$dir = "upload/";

// If File Submitted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['profile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ( in_array($ext, $valid_formats)) {
        if( $_FILES['profile']['size'] < $max_file_size ){
            $uniq = base_convert(uniqid(), 16, 10);
            $tmp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
            $uniq_file_name = $uniq.".".$ext;
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $dir.$uniq_file_name)){

$query= "INSERT INTO `studentconsultancy`.`student_registration_form` (`ID`,`FirstName`, `LastName`,`DateOfBirth`, `Email`, `LandPhone`, `CellPhone`, `Address`, `Address2`, `City`, `State`, `ZipCode`, `Country`, `InterestLevel`, `InterestLevelOther`, `EnrollYear`, `EnrollSemester`, `InterestCountry`, `InterestCountryOther`, `EnglishProficiency`, `EnglishOther`, `Score`, `Grade`, `YearOfExamTaken`, `CountryOfExamTaken`, `LastAcademicQualification`, `CourseName`, `ResultGrade`, `InstituteName`, `PassportScanCopy`, `AcademicDocumentScanCopy1`, `AcademicDocumentScanCopy2`, `AcademicDocumentScanCopy3`, `AcademicDocumentScanCopy4`, `ProfilePicture`, `NationalIDScanCopy`, `DocList`, `EntryDate`) 

VALUES ('NULL','$firstname', '$lastname', '$date', '$email', '$landphone', '$cellphone', '$address', '$address2', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$country', '$interestlevel', '$interestlevelother', '$enrollyear', '$enrollsemester', '$interestcountry', '$interestcountryother', '$englishprof', '$english_other', '$score', '$grade', '$yearofexam', '$countryofexam', '$lastacademicq', '$coursename', '$resultgrade','$institutename','$passport','$academic1','$academic2','$academic3','$academic4','$profile','$nid','$doclist',NOW())";

$msg = "Uploading successful!";
            }
            else{
                $msg = "Problem while moving file";
            }
        }
        else{
            $msg = "File is too large";
        }
    }
    else{
        $msg = "Worng file format";
    }
}

 if (!mysql_query($query,$link))
  {
  die('Error: Error in Registration,try later ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

Regards
Ishtiaque

Comment: as the single file is uploaded repeat the code for multiple file as well with their name . you can also use an array for names and loop through the array for uploading files

Comment: Can you show the php code you are using now? Showing us the form doesn't give us an idea of what you are doing server-side.

Comment: Serkfalcon please check the code above